# How to see all directories from remote?

Tags: command-line, server, directory

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 server, after I login as *sudoer*  from remote, I try to see all directories with `ls` command nut nothing happens.

I can switch to the home directory by using  `cd /home` and I see all directories with the `ls` command there.

What am I doing wrong?
Where is my position after logging into the server?

The problem is, that I probably installed something in a wrong location and I can't find it.

Update : i can create a Folder, but i can't see it... i do create for instance `mkdir /temp` and i can access it. but i cant see it in the folder before.

[image: nothing happens]

Comment: Could you show us the complete line when entering `ls`? The user name, etc..

Comment: sure i can, but it is NOTHING. btw. i forgot to add...it's a Virtual Machine.

Comment: How did you login? with ssh?

Comment: yes ssh version 2

Comment: What about dir command?

Comment: Not sure that I understand the question, but what about `ls /`? 
To check what directory you are in type `pwd`. You are probably in `/root`

Comment: thanks symin, that helped me out. if you put it as answer i will upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` list content of directory. If no directory is given it will list content of current directory.

To list content of root directory (`/`) type in `ls /`

To check what directory you are in at the moment use `pwd` command.

If you login as root normally you are placed in /root, which is empty by default.